# Can SCCM deploy a VSTO add-in without using an MSI wrapper

Tags: ms-office, vsto, sccm

Does anyone know if I NEED To wrap my Office 2007, vsto-based add-in in a MSI? It seems to be a lot of extra overhead and headache, just to have it not work anyway.

When I do get it to install, I still need to run the vsto installer, even though I have tried to use the |vstolocal switch to keep the add-in's deployment centralized.

Has anyone pulled this kind of install off successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I've deployed VSTO from SCCM without using an MSI.

The trick is a simple command line:

```
"%commonprogramfiles%/microsoft shared/VSTO/10.0/VSTOInstaller.exe" /i <path to vsto>
```

> VSTOInstaller.exe [[/install  ] | [/uninstall ]] [/silent]
> [/help]
>
> /install, /i: Install the solution. This option must be followed by
> the fully qualified path of a deployment manifest in the form http://,
> https://, or \servername\foldername.
>
> /uninstall, /u: Uninstall the solution. This option must be followed
> by the fully qualified path of a deployment manifest in the form
> http://, https://, or \servername\foldername.
>
> /silent, /s: Install or uninstall without prompting for input or
> providing information.
>
> /help, /?: Generate this help message.
>
> EXAMPLE: VSTOInstaller.exe /i \servername\foldername\AddIn.vsto

Be aware that with the /silent option "trust for the addin has to be built into the project or it will default to 'don't install' when using the silent switch." (source: [TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa84b3f6-b327-4e67-b950-3ec7b1c22fc9/delivering-vsto-via-sccm?forum=configmanagerapps))

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it, and you don't need to wrap it in an MSI if you're happy for users to manually install it. If you:

- use the publish tab in project -> properties
- setup your "publishing folder location" and "installation folder URL" properly
- set and all of the other meta-data properly, including stuff in your AssemblyInfo.cs file
- whack the "publish now" button
- share out the installation folder and email out the link
- ensure that users have the right permissions to install it (local admin I guess, you'd need to check)

It worked for me. On Windows 7 and XP too.

The whole "this publisher is untrusted" thing is a complete mess, trying to fix that involves writing some really stupid code that tells Windows that "hey, by the way, I *am* actually trusted". I didn't bother and just told people to ignore the warning.

I'm *guessing* that you only need an MSI if you want to push out the add-in using active directory and do an automated install.